# Solr search order by multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot-solr

I'm using `sunspot_solr` gem. I need to find the student's list in descending order of their `points`. If there is a tie, sort them in the descending order of `level`.

```
User.solr_search do
  with :role, :student
  with :confirmed, true
  order_by :points, :desc
  order_by :level, :desc
  paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 15
end
```

I am getting the list in the descending order of their `points`, but the result does not satisfy the second condition. I've solr indexed all the above fields.